# Consider the map $ f \colon \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ defined by $f(x,y)=(3x-2y+x^2,4x+5y+y^2).$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I came across the following problem that says:

> Consider the map $f \colon \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ defined by $$f(x,y)=(3x-2y+x^2,4x+5y+y^2)$$ Then I have to determine whether the following statements are true or not?
>   1. $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ and all directional derivatives exist at $(0,0).$
>   2. $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and the derivative $Df(0,0)$ is invertible.

The problem is that I can not compute  $Df(0,0)$.Can someone provide me the formula by means of which I can compute it. With regards and thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: $f$ is not from $\Bbb {R}$ to $\Bbb {R}$, instead, $f$ is from $\Bbb {R}^2$ to $\Bbb {R}^2$, i.e $f \colon \Bbb {R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb {R}^2$

Comment: @Paul yes.You are right. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote 
$$f_1(x,\; y)=3x-2y+x^2,\\ 
f_2(x,\; y)=4x+5y+y^2.$$
Then 
$$Df(x,\;y)=\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\partial{f_1(x,\; y)}}{\partial{x}} &&  \dfrac{\partial{f_1(x,\; y)}}{\partial{y}} \\
\dfrac{\partial{f_2(x,\; y)}}{\partial{x}} &&  \dfrac{\partial{f_2(x,\; y)}}{\partial{y}}
\end{pmatrix}$$